# Another abstract algebra/field theory question

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose that $F$ is a field, $S \subseteq F^n$ and $I$ is an ideal in $F[x_1, \cdots, x_n] = F[\bar{x}]$. Define
>   $$I(S) = \{ f \in F[\bar{x}]: f(\bar{s}) = 0, \forall \bar{s} \in S\}$$ and
>   $$V(I) = \{\bar{s} \in F^n: f(\bar{s}) = 0, \forall f \in I \} $$
>   Give an example of a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which $S \neq V(I(S))$.

I know that $I(S)$ is an ideal and I also know that $S \subseteq V(I(S))$.
I cannot think of any subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy this. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an easy approach, there exist sets $S\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ that vanishes at every point in $S$ must be identically zero, for example $S=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{\overline{s}\}$ for any point $\overline{s}=(s_1,s_2)$ (because a polynomial function is continuous in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$). Then we have $$S\neq \mathbb{R}^2=V(I(S)).$$

Comment: I'm trying to work through your answer and I don't understand it.

Comment: Suppose I tell you a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ has the property that $f(s,t)=0$ for every point $(s,t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Then in fact we must have $f(0,0)=0$ too, because $f$, considered as a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, is continuous. Thus $I(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\})=\{0\}$, the ideal consisting only of the zero polynomial, and thus $$V(I(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}))=\mathbb{R}^2.$$

Comment: That actually makes sense! Thank you. Would the open unit ball work if taken to be our $S$? $V(I)$ is closed so since $I$ is an ideal it is the intersection of finitely many zero sets of polynomials, and hence closed. So then $S \neq V(I(S))$?

Comment: Yup, that's right! For any ideal $I$, the set $V(I)=\bigcap_{f\in I}V(f)$ is an intersection of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and therefore is closed itself, so $S\neq V(I(S))$ for any non-closed set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Slowly, I am understanding. Thank you!